# How can I add condition based on the parameters of the array data on the rules Laravel?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.3, rules, required

I use Laravel 5.3

My rules Laravel like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
class AddCartRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'product_id'=>'required|numeric',
            'delivery_address'=>'required',
            'request_delivery_at' => 'required|date_format:d-m-Y H:i:s|after:120 minutes'
        ];
    }
}
```

The result of `echo '<pre>';print_r($this->request->get('delivery_address'));echo '</pre>';` like this :

```
Array
(
    [sender_name] => chelsea
    [postal] => 12345
    [country] => japan
    [city] => tokyo
    [send_date] => 09-12-2017
    [send_time] => 
    [information] => test
)
```

I want to make it like this :

If send_time is empty, the rules of request_delivery_at like this :

```
'request_delivery_at' => 'required|date_format:d-m-Y H:i:s'
```

So, it without `|after:120 minutes`

If send_time is have value (for example send_time = 12:30:00), the rules of request_delivery_at like this :

```
'request_delivery_at' => 'required|date_format:d-m-Y H:i:s|after:120 minutes'
```

How can I do it?

**Update** :

I try like this :

```
public function rules()
{
    $send_time = $this->request->get('delivery_address')['send_time'];

    if($send_time)
        $validation_time = '|after:120 minutes';
    else
        $validation_time = '';  

    return [
        'product_id'=>'required|numeric',
        'delivery_address'=>'required',
        'request_delivery_at' => 'required|date_format:d-m-Y H:i:s'.$validation_time
    ];
}
```

Seems it works

Comment: since your requirement is pretty complex, you cannot achieve it with existing validation rules, you have to create a custom validation rule,
may i know from when after 120 minutes, ?

Comment: @SuccessMan looks okay, might want to check that var isn't null before trying to access an array element though ... sidenote: the `FormRequest` is a `Request` ... `$this->all()`  `$this->input()` etc ...it is an `Illuminate\Http\Request` ... you are in the context of the request already, `$this->input('delivery_address')`

Comment: @lagbox, Okay. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear for me, so far to what i understand is, you want to have conditional validation rule, based on the send time in delivery address array's presence,

you can achieve this by creating your own validation rule or by adding validations checking conditionally in the controller it self,

controller method ex:

```
if(!$request->has('delivery_address.send_time')){
    $rules = [

    ];

    $messages = [


    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules,$messages);
    if($validator->fails()){
        $this->throwValidationException($request,$validator);
    }
}else{
  $rules = [

    ];

    $messages = [


    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules,$messages);
    if($validator->fails()){
        $this->throwValidationException($request,$validator);
    }

}
```

or you can refer the following my SO answer on how to make custom validation rule.
[Date Compare in validation Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38562603/date-compare-in-validation-laravel-5-2/38562907#38562907)

Comment: I find the simple solution. Look at my update question

Comment: the OP is using a form request